# Is there any way to revoke an outdated question, when my need is somewhat similar? Or do I have to create a new one?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, design, specific-question

I have a question similar to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/7956/46981) . It's nearly 5 years old.Is there a way to re-ask this question?
Or
Can I ask a question Similar to that without getting down voted?

Coz, I posted a question like that and got downvoted, yet I see a lot of similar questions getting answers. 
I'm asking this coz I have very less points and getting downvoted will get me to not able to comment.

Comment: That's an old shopping question from the early times when such questions were less unacceptable.  If it were asked today, it would get closed immediately.

Comment: @NickAlexeev :( where can I post my questions regarding sourcing? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

No.  This site is not for product recommendations.  We refer to such requests as *shopping questions* and close them.  Sometimes we also downvote them to oblivion since this is one of the things clearly spelled out in the site rules.  People attempting to ask shopping questions obviously just barged in here and blurted out their question without bothering to learn the ways of the site first.  That's going to piss off the members here, so they will react with downvotes for wasting their time and noising up the site.

In the early days of this site, it was still trying to find its way.  The rules were more fluid and applied more loosely.  Unfortunately, that means there are some old questions here that are bad examples, such as the one you found.  That doesn't make it right today.  I see Nick has already closed it now that he's become aware of it.

No, you can't post a similar question or try to re-ask that one.  It would get quickly closed, and you will likely get (well deserved) downvotes.  If you do this enough, you will lose the privilege of asking questions here.

If you see similar questions, flag them for moderator attention as shopping questions.  If you stick around and play by the rules, eventually you'll have enough rep to vote to close them yourself.

As to where you can post such questions, I can only so "Not here".  Anything beyond that is not the business of this site.